# UITableView programmatically made not being displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I create my table view programmatically with the following:

```
lazy var myTableView: UITableView =
{
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return tableView
}()
```

I then add it as a subview to my view in viewDidLoad:

```
view.addSubview(myTableView)
```

Then in my method where I set up all the UI constraints, I lay it out with the following:

```
myTableView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor).active = true
myTableView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(temporaryContainerView.bottomAnchor).active = true
```

Finally, here are my delegate/datasource methods:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"

    return cell
}
```

When I put breakpoints on the above methods, it seems as though that numberOfRowsinSection is being called many times, but cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't being called at all.

Why isn't it appearing?

Comment: It kind of sounds like your tableview is recognizing that none of the cells are actually on screen, which (if true) would explain why cellForRow isn't being called.  I only see constraints for width & bottom - what about a top/height attribute?  The frame defaults to 0,0,0,0, so I suspect if you're not explicitly setting a height or a top & bottom constraint it's got a height of 0.  You can check this by putting a breakpoint in your numberOfRows delegate method, and when it's frozen print out the frame of the tableview (p myTableView.frame)

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the centerXAnchor constraint on my TableView for it to be located properly along with translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false